# Can't set my background

Tags: appearance

This is mystifying me. I have tried all other solutions that I could find and none seem to work. The 'appearance' menu has disappeared from settings. I'm using gnome-classic. Here's what I've tried so far:

1) `Right click -> Change desktop background` This just brings up settings

2) `gnome-control-center background` Same as above which is annoying. It also brings up this:

```
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 12:41:31.369606] Switchboard.vala:201: Couldn't find background.plug among the loaded settings.
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 12:41:31.369641] Switchboard will not function properly.
```

3) `apt-get install gnome-control-center-unity` to which I get `E: Unable to locate package gnome-control-center-unity`

Comment: In step 2, your error mentions Switchboard and a `background.plug` file. Are you running Elementary OS or Ubuntu with the Elementary desktop? Or having you installed the Elementary desktop in the past but now using gnome-classic?

Comment: Actually, now you mention it, I did yes. I briefly installed it but it didn't work so I *thought* I removed it.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? If 13.04, did you try reinstalling gnome-classic using `sudo apt-get purge gnome-session-fallback;sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback`

Comment: Currently on 12.04. Will that work on this version?

Comment: Can you do this: `sudo apt-cache check` and `sudo apt-get -yqq install debsums; debsums -s`? If the first fails edit your question and add the results, if the second produce output the same.

Comment: Yes, it should work the same way.

Comment: @Jobin - That doesn't seem to work. @Braiam - I get this error with the first command: `E: Invalid operation check`

Comment: @andy my mistake, is `sudo apt-get check` not cache. BTW, you can only ping 1 person per comment, if you need to ping several at once just create one comment for each.

Comment: Is the wallpaper stored on another partiton? If yes, move it to your ubuntu partition.

Comment: @Braiam Ah right, well it completed fine. No errors!

Comment: @the_Seppi Nope same partition.

Comment: Can you do `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove` and install `sudo apt-get install debsums` and run `debsums -s`?

Comment: Sure: http://pastebin.com/W7VbmNiS

Comment: What file-permissions do the background-files have ? (*.jpeg) - you need at least to chmod 555 or chmod 755 <filename>. Could be that directory has not proper permissions too ?

Comment: Lets try setting a custom background, by finding a picture, downloading it, and then rightclicking it, --> set as desktop background. Tell me if it works or not.

Comment: I've tried both and it doesn't seem to be an issue with the actual pictures themselves. I just can't get to the screen to change the wallpaper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to followup: I never managed to fix the problem concerning the wallpaper dialog but I found a workaround to change it from the command line with this little script:

```
#! /bin/bash

path=$(cd $(dirname $1); pwd)/$(basename $1)
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file://$path
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the control-center-unity package was deleted. Have you tried installing the .Deb package of control-center-unity from http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/saucy/main/base/gnome-control-center-unity ?

Comment: Thanks for this! Although, I'm trying to install it and it says I'm missing `libgnome-desktop-3-7 (>= 3.2.0)`

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://pkgs.org/download/libgnome-desktop-3-7 If nothing else works, try purging gnome-classic and re-installing. as @jobin suggested. I think part of the problem might be an unmet dependency during the initial installation of gnome-classic.

Comment: Hmm, this is super frustrating. The first option didn't work and neither did `apt-get purge gnome-panel && apt-get install gnome-panel`

Comment: Taking a wild chance, you could try installing Ubuntu-tweak tool and enabling desktop icons? No logic to my answer, but just that a few others have had this help.

Comment: That does help somewhat. I can right click on the desktop now and 'Change desktop background' but that just brings up the settings dialogue. Very weird

Answer (score 1):

Try going to synaptic and look for the packages

> libgnome-control-center

you will probably see

> libgnome-control-center-dev
>
> libgnome-control-center1

Install them both and then try to access to your desktop settings to see.

Comment: libgnome-control-center-dev wasn't installed, but I still can't see the appearance menu

Comment: Precisely, if it wasn't installed that's the missing component, just mark it for installation and apply the changes.

Comment: Sorry, I should've made it clear: It wasn't installed but it wasn't in the settings once I did end up installing it.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the gnome panel.
Type in the terminal following code:

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-panel && sudo apt-get install gnome-panel.
```

Comment: I've already tried that but it doesn't seem to fix the problem